# Characteristic function in integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, characteristic-functions

Why is depending on $y\in\mathbb{R}$  $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\cdot\chi_{(0,x)}(y)\operatorname{d}x = \int_y^1 \frac{1}{x}\operatorname{d}x\cdot\chi_{(0,1)}(y),$$

where $\chi_A(y) =\begin{cases} 1&, y\in A \\0&, y\not\in A\end{cases}$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The simpliest would be to find these integrals explicitly as functions of $y$. Conceptually - look what the values of $x$ in the first integral such that the integrand is non-zero.

Comment: Yes - as a function of $y$ the integral should be non-zero on $]0,y]$ and zero on $]y,1]$, or not? But why then does remain only the second part of the integral? I must be wrong..

Comment: No, it's the other way around… zero on $[0,y]$ and non-zero on $]y,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Let $y \not\in [0,1]$ then $\chi_{(0,x)}(y) = 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ hence $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\cdot\chi_{(0,x)}(y)\operatorname{d}x = 0$$

Otherwise for $y \in [0,1]$ it holds $$\chi_{(0,x)}(y) = \begin{cases} 1, & x > y \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

So $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\cdot\chi_{(0,x)}(y)\operatorname{d}x = \int_y^1 \frac{1}{x}\operatorname{d}x$$

Summarized:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\cdot\chi_{(0,x)}(y)\operatorname{d}x = \begin{cases} 0, & y \not\in[0,1] \\ \int_y^1 \frac{1}{x}\operatorname{d}x, & y \in [0,1] \end{cases} = \int_y^1 \frac{1}{x}\operatorname{d}x\cdot\chi_{(0,1)}(y)$$